# How to read file which has delimitor with in the double quotes

Tags: sas

I have to read a file with a tab delimited x'05'c (dlm='0C'x). For few records the delimiter is present with in the string which has a double quotes. when I'm using '&' in the input statement it is working fine but records with more than one space is giving error.

Data I have to read:

```
1.AIRWORLDWIDE.z1234565
2.MEDICAL.y121546
3."INPUTTTFAM.ILY TRUST"
```

Output desired:

```
ID     text           text_ref
-----------------------------------
1     AIRWORLDWIDE   z1234565
2     MEDICAL        y121546
3     "INPUTTTFAM    ILY TRUST"
```

My program :

```
Data Want;

format id $char1.
text $char12.
text_ref $char12.;

informat id $char1.
text $char12.
text_ref $char12.;

length id text text_ref;

infile have dlm='0C'x dsd END=eof missover ;

input id text text_ref;

/* input id (text text_ref) (& $12.);  */

run;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSD is not the INFILE option you want here.

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
data want;
   infile FT15F001 dlm='.' missover;
   informat id $char1. text $char12. text_ref $char12.;
   input (_all_)(:);
   list;
   parmcards;
1.AIRWORLDWIDE.z1234565
2.MEDICAL.y121546
3."INPUTTTFAM.ILY TRUST"
;;;;
   run;
proc contents varnum;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you please explain bit more, why we shouldn't use DSD???